# About the keyword of `self`

Tags: objective-c

```
+ (void)Foo;
- (void)Foo;
```

In the method, `- (void)Foo`, the keyword `self` means an instance of the class.
But in the method, `+ (void)Foo`, What does the keyword `self` mean? Does it mean the `Class` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` is one of the two implicit parameters to every method.  It is a pointer to an object, and initially it is whatever object received the message to invoke the method that's executing.  When the method in  question is an instance method, `self` will be an instance of the class in which the method is defined, or one of its subclasses.  In the case of a class method, `self` will be the class object.

Comment: Which is also exactly why Objective-C's class methods can be subclassed whereas Java's cannot.....

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The following works just fine:

```
+(id)myObjectWithInt:(NSInteger)anInt {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithInt:anInt] autorelease];
}
```