# What is "self" in a classmethod

Tags: objective-c, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About the keyword of `self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146660/about-the-keyword-of-self)
>   [Why is `self` allowed in static context in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325453/why-is-self-allowed-in-static-context-in-objective-c)

what type of object is the `self` object in a class method?

Example:

```
+ (void)test {
 NSLog(@"class self: %@", self); 
}
```

Is the `self` object in a class method a fully initialized object of the class or only a class wrapper object for the important meta data ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` in class method has type `Class` and points to the class object. You can send messages to it just like you send them to the class:

```
+ (void) classMethod; {
    // the same
    MyClass* a = [[self alloc] init];
    MyClass* b = [[MyClass alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: is there an Apple-Docu for the class object?

Comment: Yes, if you look it up in the Organizer window, it leads to the definition `typedef struct objc_class *Class;`.  (So, maybe not so much an object in that you don't use `Class *`.)

Comment: ok thx, it is a good old struct. With many infos for the name, ivars, etc..

Comment: @PhillipMills It's just a syntactic irregularity (just like `id` instead of `id*`). Class object is a real object: you can send messages, it contains information about its own class (called metaclass) etc.

Comment: @meccan There is no standard interface for class objects (except `alloc` methods maybe). You're not supposed to know about their ivars and implementation (if only out of curiosity, then you can look at source code of Obj-C runtime). What can be done to them is only described by `+` methods syntax.